# Django html interacts with views

Tags: python, html, django

I have a html that contains some forms and buttons. One button corresponds to a file that I have uploaded. I want to achieve when I click on a button, my views will act on the corresponding file, and shows the results in another html like picture  below.

How can I give each button specific parameters from my models? and how to get the parameter in my views.

[image]

I tried this code, but failed to get it. is this right?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" name={{item.description}}></button>
```

Comment: For your purpose you must use `<a>` instead of `<button>` to href you must pass route name in route you catch this url and do your view function and return Response with html. I reccomend to you read the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: thanks. and how to achieve this：each time I click on one button ,the right HTML just update  the content in it

Comment: You want to update content, or reload page, i think you mean reload and return new response because for update content you must use ajax, and this way more harder for you now

Comment: yes, but i have lots of files, if one file corresponds a HTML , then i need lots of htmls, could reload just use one html ?

Comment: You can use one html and pass to this html different context by third parameter to `render()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do something like that:
You should add new route for your new page to `routes.py`:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^new-page/$', views.new_page_view, 'new_page'),
]
```

after that your views.py must have your view function, that will execute when you go to url `/new-page/`

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render    

def new_page_view(request, question_id):
    return render(request, 'path/to/your/template')
```

You can read more about `render()` [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/)

In your template (When you want to add your link button) you must add following string:

```
<a href="{% url 'new_page' %}">Link to new Page</a>
```

Something loke that you must do with your project.
More about this you can read [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/)

I hope this answer will help you

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem if I use <a>, I have so many files and I will have more, if one file corresponds one HTML, that's too many

Comment: I told that you can use one html file to many pages, please read the django tutorial, becouse i can`t explaine you all doccumentation